# Dual Boot Issue, Windows 7 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I just wanted to give you my bootlog and see whether anyone can help me. I have already applied the recommended boot repair solution, I get to see GRUB now but Windows 7 is not listed. Your help is very much appreciated

my bootlog: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5564838/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already tried `sudo update-grub` but grub still doesn't detect Windows, you can try **manually inserting** the grub menu entry below in the relevant section (where you have the lines "`### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###`" and "`### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###`" and nothing in between) by entering `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` in terminal, and then saving and rebooting your computer.

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-1A8422008421DECF' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  1A8422008421DECF
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1A8422008421DECF
    fi
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

**If this solves the problem** and Windows 7 does work, you might like to make this manual solution permanent by entering the entry also to this system file **/etc/grub.d/40_custom**

**If this doesn't solve the problem**, you might need your **Windows 7 installation disk** to repair its bootloader by booting from it and going to **recovery** mode. It should be adequate to use the **fixboot** only (and not the **fixmbr** option) so as not to override the **grub2 bootloader**.

*Note: I also have (pre-installed) Windows 7 and (user-installed) Ubuntu 12.10 (both 64-bit) working flawlessly, although I never use Windows (I don't know why I don't delete it ;-)*

Comment: thanks a bunch Sadi, I'll try this once I get home, currently in the office. I'll let you know of the results.

Comment: alright, tried your method. It does add the Windows 7 option to my GRUB interface, but as no boot manager is linked to it, it fails to boot and asks for the boot manager. Now, how do I link my boot manager file or set of files to this Windows 7 entry?

Comment: your windows 7 boot manager is probably broken - see: last option mentioned above.

Comment: well,I don't have a Windows 7 Installation Disk, I can prepare a bootable USB if it's any help though. so, in your method, the Windows 7 entry is already linked to my Windows' boot manager. I don't know how it got corrupted though, it was just fine before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Once mine was corrupted too because I changed the Windows partition size from Ubuntu I guess. Maybe you can obtain a **Windows Recovery Disk** in some way , e.g. a relatively small **iso file** that can be downloaded. It merely includes so disk maintenance tools specifically for Windows 7.

Comment: **http://bootfromcd.com/data-recovery/windows-7-recovery-disk/**

Comment: Out of curiosity I've just tried and managed to get Windows Recovery Disk image file (iso) added to my **MultiSystem Live USB** under **SysLinux** sub-menu: **http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install**

Comment: wow, that's great. I'll download and see, is there and English version?

Comment: Don't worry, it's installed in English as well. I think it's the best live USB disk creator.

Comment: so, what it basically does is it contains boot files for various platforms and other common fixes, meaning with this; one doesn't need separate Windows or Ubuntu boot repair solutions?

Comment: Yes, if you add to your MultiSystem Live USB Disk all those systems and tools which can help you with various repair/recovery solutions, e.g. Ubuntu, Parted Magic (inc. Clonezilla), Rescatux, Redo, Windows 7 Recovery Disk, UBCD4Win, etc. you no longer need numerous live CDs and DVDs.

Comment: used the live USB, there's no such option to fix windows 7 boot manager in it.

Comment: If you have successfully added **Windows Recovery Disk iso image** to your **MultiSystem Live USB**, when you boot your computer with it, you should select the **SysLinux** menu further below, which will take you to another menu, including an item called **Windows install** (not a good name), and when you click it, your computer should start in **Windows Recovery Mode**. There you should find your way to **fixboot** command.

Comment: Alright, I did create the windows recovery live usb successfully and managed to boot into windows; fixed using the live usb and added the lines you mentioned to my grub but it still doesn't work. I deleted my reserve partition so it means that my windows boot loader is in my first partition, EDEN. how can I tell Grub to look for the boot manager over there?

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake by deleting Windows' System Reserved partition. I haven't used Windows for a number years now (since XP) but I think it's created and required by Windows to boot. You should try and return your PC to previous state, and try running sudo grub-update in Ubuntu to have Windows properly included in grub menu.

Comment: yeps, it worked. No two versions of Windows show up in my grub, I think Windows boot manager is loaded in the reserved partition and the first NTFS partition at the same time. The reserved partition is only used when it couldn't be found where Windows is installed I believe. haven't tried the entries yet but they're over there at least. I did it by rerunning Boot-Repair after I fixed Windows boot files, I believe grub managed to detect it now and fixed the entries.

Comment: I'm glad it's been finally solved. But it seems you should delete the manual Windows entry now.

Comment: only one problem is on the way to a great Ubuntu experience, the freakin' fake floppy drive. There's no option in my BIOS to disable it and I've tried blacklisting it in Ubuntu as well, of which hasn't work obviously. It's there and everytime I go in, I have to manually disable it; plus there's a few system errors before I disable mounting it, or sometimes even after.