# Removing System Reserved to use GRUB2

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, bootloader

Today I was reading a lot about the boot process. I have win7 ubuntu multiboot, grub2 is the loader. My question is:
Is it safe to delete System Reserved (BOOTMGR in it), as I use GRUB2?
I mean:
Does the GRUB2 loads win7 itself, 
or does it load the BOOTMGR which then loads win7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user who asked the question [Dual Boot Issue, Windows 7 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261107/dual-boot-issue-windows-7-64-bit-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit/261163#261163) confirmed (further down in the comments section) that Grub2 can load Win7 even after the System Reserved partition is deleted.

But perhaps you can first make a backup of the partition, format it and make sure it works for you as well before deleting the partition.

Comment: I would `sudo update-grub` after deleting the partition not to be faced by a Grub rescue prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It did work, but this is how: 
1)Deleted the System Reserved. Windows 7 stopped booting at all. 
2)Ran Win7 CD - Recovery -> Startup Recovery (or something) multiple times (I had to do it 3 times). 
3)In GRUB I marked the Win7 partition as 'boot'.

From here I tried again the Win7 recovery in combination with adding manualy an entry to GRUB Customizer, until GRUB somehow evetually was able to find by itself the win7.